# JAX-WS MTOM or BindingType annotation

Tags: binding, wsdl, jax-ws, mtom

I am bit confuse in understanding the concept of  MTOM in JAX-WS service .
I have a webservice exposing a method that returns an Image .
Below is the  SIB  and publisher  code

```
//@MTOM
@WebService(endpointInterface= "com.test.clear.TestImageInterface")
@BindingType(value = SOAPBinding.SOAP11HTTP_MTOM_BINDING)
public class TestImageImpl implements TestImageInterface{


@WebMethod
@Override
// Create a named image from the raw bytes.
public Image getImageByName(String name) {

    Path path = Paths.get("..\..\..\"+name);

try {

    byte[ ] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(path);
    ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
    Iterator iterators = ImageIO.getImageReadersByFormatName("jpeg");
    ImageReader iterator = (ImageReader) iterators.next();
    ImageInputStream iis = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(in);
    iterator.setInput(iis, true);
    return iterator.read(0);
}
catch(IOException e) {
    System.err.println(e);
return null;
}
}

}
```

publisher >>

```
Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:8080/TestWS/getImage", new TestImageImpl());
```

The confusion i have is to understand when to use  @MTOM and when to use  @BindingType annotation .
If i use either one of the annotation or  use  both together  , i do not see any difference in the WSDL published by the publisher class .
Below is the generated WSDL

```
<wsp:Policy wsu:Id="TestImageImplPortBinding_MTOM_Policy">
<ns1:OptimizedMimeSerialization xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy/optimizedmimeserialization" wsp:Optional="true"/>
```

```
<binding name="TestImageImplPortBinding" type="tns:TestImageInterface">
<wsp:PolicyReference URI="#TestImageImplPortBinding_MTOM_Policy"/>
<soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/>

...
...
</definitions>
```

Also i do not see any difference in SOAP response got from Service . ie: i got
    < Xop:include href:cid / >   and got file as attachment in

Does that mean to enable MTOM at server side  one can use either one of the annotation ?

I tried to set MTOM programmatically at publisher side after removing both the annotations from SIB like below :

```
SOAPBinding binding = (SOAPBinding) endpoint.getBinding();
binding.setMTOMEnabled(true);
```

But then WSDL generated was not having  MTOM policy at all.

So when one needs to set MTOM programmatically ?

Can some one explain the working of  MIME type and MTOM .

Thanks much in advance .

Answer (score 0):

I have got answer of the above posted question here >>
[ http://itdoc.hitachi.co.jp/manuals/3020/30203Y2310e/EY230716.HTM ]
[[image: <code>Table-30</code>]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6Mkd.png)

Thank you everyone .

Comment: Why MTOM can not be enabled on  WS that implements  Provider interface ?